# Determiner all + uncountable noun - which of the following sentences is correct?

Tags: determiners, uncountable-nouns

All water **has** been filtered.

or

All water **have** been filtered.

?

I've already searched about this especially in youtube. From what I learned, if it's an uncountable noun after determiner all, it will be treated as singular therefore **has** should be used.

I just need a confirmation that's why I posted a question here.

Comment: But you still need a definite article, since you are referring to a specific volume of water. "All (of) *the* water has been filtered." (of) is optional.

Comment: No article is needed. The first example would be understandable, colloquial English as it might appear on a water container.

Answer (score 1):

Since water is uncountable, it always takes a singular verb, unless you refer to different water bodies (lakes, rivers, etc), in which case you could say waters and then use 'have'. But in your example, the correct one is - All the water has been filtered.